# While compilation it shows error at int rand = rand.nextInt(3);

Tags: java

I'm creating a Rock Paper Scissors game using Java. During compilation, it throws an error for generating a random number. I use a random class but still, it throws an error.

This is the error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
   Cannot invoke nextInt(int) on the primitive 
   type int
   -Duplicate local variable rand
```

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
  
public class rockpaperscissors {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Game");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
       System.out.print("What is your move? Choose any of the following r rock, paper, or scissors ");
      System.out.print("To quit the game, enter quit");
      Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
      String Mymove=sc.nextLine();
      System.out.print("If you want to quit , Please write QUIT");
      if(Mymove.equals("QUIT")) {
          break;
      }
           
            
            if(!Mymove.equals("ROCK") || !Mymove.equals("SCISSORS") || !Mymove.equals("PAPER"))
            {System.out.print("Invalid");
            }
            else {
                
                System.out.print("Proceed");
            }
            
            Random rand = new Random();
             int rand = rand.nextInt(3); //in this section error occurs. Can you please suggest me   
                
             String opponentMove = "";
           if( rand==0)
               {opponentMove="ROCK";
               }
  else if(rand==1)
       {opponentMove="PAPER";
       }
       
       else {
           opponentMove="SCISSORS";
       
       }
           
            if(Mymove.equals(opponentMove))
            {
                System.out.println("Tie!");
            }
            else if(Mymove.equals("ROCK") && opponentMove.equals("SCISSORS"))
            {System.out.println("You are Won! Congrats ");
            
            }
            
            else if(Mymove.equals("PAPER") && opponentMove.equals("ROCK"))
                    {System.out.println("Computer Won! Congrats ");
                    }
                    
            else if(Mymove.equals("PAPER") && opponentMove.equals("SCISSORS"))
                    {
                System.out.println("Computer Won! Congrats ");
                    }
                    }

            
        
        }

    
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what's the error? Include the stack trace, please.

Comment: 1)  What error does it throw?  Add all relevant details to the question body.  2) Please use an appropriate title that describes the problem.  We don't want your life story, and other padding in the title; e.g. stuff like *"How to resolve this error? Can you please suggest me. I am a beginner in java"*.

Comment: I notice that you have two variables declared (one after the other!) with the name `rand`.  You can't do that.  And besides ... calling two different things (a random number generator, and a random number) would be confusing.

Comment: OK ... so my previous comment explains your compilation error.  (Note: the compiler does not "throw" compilation errors.  Compilation errors are not exceptions.  If you want people to *understand* your programming questions, it is important that you use the correct terminology.)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring "rand" 2 types as "Random" class object, and "int(Integer)" object. Just copy paste these 2 lines in your code:

```java
Random randObj = new Random();
int rand = randObj.nextInt(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate variable name is pretty straightforward - you have two variables named `rand`.  This is simple to repair - rename one of the following.

```
   Random rand = new Random();
   int rand = rand.nextInt(3);
```

The other compilation error is probably a side effect of the first.  The compiler cannot determine which `rand` you are trying to invoke `nextInt(int)` on so it opts for the wrong one.  Solve the first problem and this one goes away.